# npx mix watch giving different results to npx mix --production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel-mix

So I have a laravel / react application that I am developing. The javascript is compiled with laravel mix.

In the company I work for we have an external package that we use in all of our products for brand consistency. This package essentially is a bunch of components that we can re-use everywhere very easily.

Recently I updated the package to have a new component and also updating functionality of some existing components. I finished those changes and published the new version of the package and then in the main project I updated the package version in the package.json so that I could use all these new features / component I just added. After updating the package version number in package.json I ran `npm install` and then `npx mix watch` to work on integrating these new features into my application and everything went well and was working fine.

Once my work was done and tested by myself I went to push the changes to staging for review but the changes / features I had added to the external package didn't seem to be working properly.

Long story short I came to realise that locally, when I run `npx mix watch` and view the site that way, everything works fine however, when I run `npx mix --production` (which is also what is being run on the server staging environment when it gets built) I have the same problem where the features I added to the package are not working.

I have no idea what is causing this and why everything is working fine with `npx run watch` and why it isnt working with `npx mix --production` and I dont really know where to look to debug?

I have tried looking at the console, I have looked at the terminal running `--verbose` with both commands to see if there is any output that might be useful but I can't identify anything wrong. I have tried making changes to the external package for the sake of just publishing a new version and just hoping that might trigger something. I have tried clearing the cache of npm, browser cache, everywhere I can think there may be cache basically.

I'm just at a loss for where to look and what might be causing this...

Please let me know if you need any more info. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your "devDependencies" packages list, maybe someone is required even on production (node ENV=production).